# Router location doesn't finish updating after history.push()

Tags: node.js, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom to navigate to different pages in my app. I have been testing things all day long and with different scenarios end up with the following:

- I target an invalid path, which should redirect me to the home path
- I push/replace the history
- the browser URL updates fine
- but the location doesn't finish updating, I end up stuck in a half baked value such as this (rendering stops half way):

```
 location: {"action":"REPLACE","location":{"pathname":"/home","search":"","hash":"","state":null,"key":"ui1fiedd"}}
```

Whereas a correct value would be:

```
location={"pathname":"/home","search":"","hash":"","state":null,"key":"ui1fiedd"}
```

This happens when I use different approaches:

- call `history.push(newPath)`
- render `<Redirect to="/home" />`
- render `<Redirect to={{ pathname: "/home" }} />`
- with or without the push option
- getting location from `withRouter`, from `useLocation()`, or from a `Route render` call

I don't have a good clean test case right now, all of this is in a pretty complex and big app. But does this ring any bell? I am surely doing something wrong, but have been looking at it all day and cannot see it.

My dependencies are:

- "react": "^16.13.1",
- "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
- "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",

Thanks!

**Edit 8/9/2020**

This looks to be a package version issue... I had recently done a few updates. Thought this might the issue, so reverted my package.json, ran `npm i` and thought I was ok...
I just wiped my modules, package-lock.json and re-ran `npm i`, now all is fine.

So the following transition screwed things up somewhere:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.9.8"   >>     "^4.11.0"
"history": "^4.10.1"            >>     "^5.0.0"
"react-helmet": "^5.2.1"        >>     "^6.1.0"
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"    >>     "^5.2.0"
"react-scripts": "^3.4.1"       >>     "3.4.1"
```

I should have looked at this ^5.0.0 version more closely :-)

Mind you, I also had really strange behaviour at the same time with this transition:

```
"react-tabulator": "^0.10.3"    >>     "^0.13.2"
```

Some pages containing tabulator tables could not load at all any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues were due to some incompatibility between some package/scripts versions, as described in the question's body.